# What is the largest (dense, real, symmetric) random matrix I can diagonalize on a computer?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, diagonalization

I have read that 10.000x10.000 is no problem for LAPACK or similar routines. I would like to know if N=20.000 or 40.000 is possible.

EDIT: I don't know if it is relevant, but the matrix is positive definite!

Also (less important) if you have done it, how long did it take? I hear diagonalization of a N=1000 random takes about 1s and the scaling is O(N^3).

Thank you

Comment: I'm not an expert in numerical linear algebra, but I would guess that the answer very much depends on a number of other things, e.g. (1) is it positive definite? (2) What's the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number)? (3) To which degree of precision do you want to have the diagonalization? (4) If it has very small eigenvalues, do you mind if they are treated as $0$? etc etc...

Comment: @Peter Franek Oh, thanks! It is positive definite. About the condition number I dont know. I hear this now for the first time. The precision is tricky. I need the eigenvalues to put them in errorfunctions of which I calculate products of the form $[1+erf(lamda_1)][1+erf(lamda_2)...]$. So, if an eigenvalue appears very often I need it very precise.

Comment: I cannot see a problem provided that your matrix fits in the memory of a computer you want to use. A "40k" matrix seems still "doable" in a reasonable amount of time. You just should be aware that if you double the size of the matrix, a result would be computed in about 8 times more the time.

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you very much! That was my thinking. But I read this [link](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/lapack-forum/archives/lapack/msg00827.html) It seems that - at the time that was written - although the matrix fitted in the memory, it still would not be diagonalized. I already asked on the LAPACK forums about the doable size nowadays, but got no reply. So I hope to find someone with experience here.

Comment: @user1816316 Ah indeed, I forgot about the 32bit integer limitations. You might try then to compile the LAPACK library with 64bit (8 byte) integers. E.g., with `gfortran`, it's the `-fdefault-integer-8` option. That might fix the issue.